# Django, React-Redux TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when listing response data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect, use-state, http-status-code-500

I've been trying to solve this issue for hours and cannot seem to find the issue. For my code as follows I keep getting the error cannot read property 'map" of undefined:

```
const Airlines = ({ isAuthenticated}) => {
   if (isAuthenticated === false) return <Redirect to="/login" />;

   const [airlineListings, setAirlineListings] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     window.scrollTo(0, 0);

     const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await axios.get(
           `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/airlines/?page=1`
          );

          setAirlineListings(res.data.results);
    
       } catch (err) {}
    };

    fetchData();
 }, []);

 const displayListings = () => {
   let display = [];
   let result = [];

   airlineListings.map((listing) => {
     return display.push(
       <AirlineCard
         title={listing.title}
         photo_main={listing.photo_main}
         slug={listing.slug}
       />
     );
   });

   for (let i = 0; i < airlineListings.length; i += 12) {
     result.push(
       <div key={i}>
         <div className="row">
           <div className="col-1-of-4">{display[i]}</div>
           <div className="col-1-of-4">
              {display[i + 1] ? display[i + 1] : null}
           </div>
          ...
```

Even though my initial state for setAirlineListings is empty array, I can't think of what else could be wrong?

Comment: please show log of `res.data.results`

Comment: right now its's showing undefined but there's definitely data there

Comment: @AlysonRace, check whether the retrieved airlineListings is an Array. seems like it's a JSON

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Thanks I think that may be the issue.